# How to nest the two selects together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a stored procedure that gives me the latest PM date for all job numbers into the current jobs query. The current jobs query is below:

```
SELECT      
    [dbo].[ServiceTicket].[FormID]
    ,[dbo].[Job].[JobNumber]
    ,[dbo].[ServiceTicket].[EditTS] AS 'LastVisitDate'  
    ,[CustomerName]
    ,[ShiptoCity]
    ,[dbo].[JobType].[Description] AS 'JobTypeName'     
    ,[dbo].[EquipmentList].TagNumber
    ,[dbo].[Technician].[Name]
    ,[dbo].[JobStatus].[Description] AS 'JobStatus'
    ,[dbo].[Equipment].[EquipmentName]
    ,[dbo].[Equipment].[Amount]
    ,[dbo].[EquipmentList].[EquipmentMake]
FROM   
    [dbo].[Job]     
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[JobType] ON [dbo].[Job].JobTypeID = [dbo].[JobType].ID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[ServiceTicket] ON [dbo].[Job].JobNumber = [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobNumber
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[EquipmentList] ON [dbo].[ServiceTicket].FormID = [dbo].[EquipmentList].LastFormID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Technician] ON [dbo].[ServiceTicket].FormID = [dbo].[Technician].FormID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[JobStatus] ON [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobStatus = [dbo].[JobStatus].ID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Equipment] ON [dbo].[EquipmentList].LastFormID = [dbo].[Equipment].[FormID]
WHERE  
    [dbo].[Job].[JobNumber] NOT IN ('1')
    AND [dbo].[EquipmentList].[EquipmentStatusId] = 1 --Rented 
    AND [dbo].[Job].JobTypeID BETWEEN 1 AND 6
    AND [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobStatus IN (1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10)
    AND [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobNumber NOT IN (SELECT JobNumber 
                                                FROM [dbo].[ServiceTicket] 
                                                WHERE  [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobStatus IN (4,7))
ORDER BY 
    [dbo].[Job].Jobnumber
```

The query below is what I want to put into, nested?, the query above:

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[ServiceTicket].[JobNumber]
    ,Max(EditTS) As 'LastPMDate'
FROM 
    [dbo].[ServiceTicket]
WHERE 
    servicetickettype IN (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,7)
GROUP BY
    [dbo].[ServiceTicket].[JobNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting could mean a lot of things but I'm guessing you want to add LastPMDate to your select. One way to do this is to use an inline view in the FROM clause

```
...

 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ServiceTicket]
        ON [dbo].[Job].JobNumber = [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobNumber

 INNER JOIN ( SELECT [dbo].[ServiceTicket].[JobNumber] ,Max(EditTS) As'LastPMDate'
           FROM [dbo].[ServiceTicket] 
           WHERE servicetickettype IN (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,7)
           Group By [dbo].[ServiceTicket].[JobNumber]) AS editTime
 ON  [dbo].[ServiceTicket].JobNumber = editTime. JobNumber 
...
```

Then you'll be able to add LastPMDate to your SELECT

You could also use what is called in SQL Server a Common Table Expression or WITH clause in ORACLE and DBMS.

You could also add this Select to the SELECT clause and add the join criteria to the WHERE clause in nested SQL the but I don't recommend that